# Can I make my Telegram bot for private chat only (not groups)?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to prevent my bot from being invited into groups and for it to only be available for private chat? I intend to create a bot that will give user-specific information and this would be confusing within a group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can use `/setjoingroups` command in [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather).

BTW, there has [leaveChat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#leavechat), you can leave yourself if your bot joined group before set this.

Answer (score 0):

When receiving a message, check if the chatid and userid is the same, if so, ignore.